# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when connecting to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I started getting this exception this morning. Not sure what's causing it or how to resolve it. When I start up my Visual studio and connect to our development TFS instance, it fails with the exception "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working". Got the following information from Event Viewer

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   Stack:
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative.FinishDataStoreInit(IntPtr, Int32, Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.Datastore.FinishDataStoreInit(Int32, Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(System.String, System.Object)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(System.Type, System.Object)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(System.Type, System.Object)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(System.Type)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPackage.get_WorkItemStore()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPackage.DoUpdateContext(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.RefreshReason, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPackage.b__0(System.Object, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.MVVM.QueuedCommandExecuteEventArgs)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.MVVM.QueuedCommandWorker.DoWork(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Internal.TfsBackgroundWorkerManager.worker_DoWork(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(System.Object)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, System.Object[] ByRef)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>   Blockquote

I ran devenv /resetuserdata and reapir the installation but that didn't help. If I am not connected to TFS, it works just fine. Also I was able to connect to other instance of TFS.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have just had exactly the same symptom in VS 2015 after upgrading from VS 2013.  Every time I opened a connection to TFS or a project that had TFS links it crashes VS2015 (even with Update 1)

I found a way to fix the crash in VS2015 without re-installing.

1. Shut VS2015.
2. For VS2015 and TFS 2015 - Remove the contents of this directory:
   C:\Users\yourUserId\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache  (I think 6.0 represents TFS 2015)
3. Then restart Visual Studio.

I believe this will be the same for VS2013 (but if you are using an older TFS then substitute 6.0 with 5.0 (TFS 2013?), 4.0 (TFS 2010?)

Comment: I had issues removing the files but restarted my machine, removed the files and then the error went away. I was receiving it when trying to 'Get Latest Version'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the files in my local AppData folder got corrupted. Tried deleting them but it didn't help it. Resolved the issue by doing the following

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2013.
2. Uninstall TFS 2013 Power Tools.
3. Manually removed the Visual Studio installation directory and all
   references from registry.
4. Re-install Visual Studio 2013 and than
   Visual Studio 2014 update 4.
5. Re-installed TFS 2013 Power Tools